Is there a way to get the Hardware ID's from all my computers from my local network
So im trying to get a bunch of computers into Microsoft Entra ID. Is there another way to get Hardware ID's from computers remote other than logging into each computer and go into device manager??
I have tried this comand into powershell: wmic csproduct get uuid. But i dont know if this is the Hardware id. Plus this still means that I have to log into each computer to get it.

You can register and join computers into Entra and also enroll them in Intune and/or AutoPilot. Which of these are you looking to do? They each have their own requirements. If you're looking at AutoPilot, you can collect the hardware hash using one of the 4 methods mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/autopilot/add-devices#collect-the-hardware-hash
